# loading bar inside listView

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm creating an app, that loads 2 xmls in listView (second one is loading when first scrolled down to the bottom).

So I want to show loading bar when 2nd xml is loading and parsing inside listView like on the second pic;
[image: First picture]
[image: Second Picture]

Is this even possible? :)

Because I have to put it on the layout and move my listView (thats not looking good).

Thanks

Comment: add all views in a single xml file and make them visible/invisible as u need

Comment: yes, but when im adding loading bar near the list (at the bottom) - my list moving top, so when i dont need loading bar list is still short and its a white line at the screen bottom

Comment: please post ur code

Comment: somehow, i put progressBar on my listView in relative layout and its worked.
Now just using setVisibility() to show/hide it

Comment: Yes. You are on right track

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For first time loading you want progress bar to be loaded in screen center. so you make in your layout two element. one listview that covers whole screen and after that put progressview ... put them in master layout as Relative, so they will automatically adjust like listeview will be behind and progressview will be on top of it. in activity code set progressview visible on your server request. after first load when items are all loaded in adapter, hide progressview ...

for on scroll and infinite scrolling/loading here is a decent library that does that easily https://github.com/pwittchen/InfiniteScroll